# How to convert special symbols in web scraping with R?

Tags: r

I am learning how to scrape the web with the `XML` and the `RCurl` packages. All goes well except for one thing. Special characters like ö or č they are read in differently into R. For instance the í is read in as ÃƒÂ­. I assume the latter is some sort of HTML coding for the first.

I have been looking for a way to convert these characters but I have not found it. I am sure other people have stumbled upon this problem as well, and I suspect there must be some sort of function to convert these characters. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of the code, sorry I did not provide it earlier.

```
library(XML)
url <-   'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles'
tables <- readHTMLTable(url)
Sec <- tables[[6]]
pl1R1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(Sec[,2]), ' '))[seq(2,32, 4)]
enc2utf8(pl1R1) # does not seem to work
```

Comment: This is an enconding issue and you probably want to convert your file to UTF-8. Look at `iconv` function, there's also an `enconding` parameter in many XML functions

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the right direction! I looked into the function, but I need to specify the original encoding in the `from` argument. I also looked into the `htmlParse` function. You can specify the encoding there, but it will autmatically pick up the encoding when present in the html-file. Apparently the encoding is not present in the html file, otherwise the function would have picked it up. I need to specify the encoding manually, but how do I know the encoding?

Comment: I'm using Linux and I know that my locale is UTF-8 so everytime I have a file, I use `enconding = UTF-8`. Concerning iconv is true that is difficult sometimes to know the from but the there's `enc2native` and `enc2utf8` and they don't require to know the encoding fo the file. Hope it helps, but with your code + the url you want to parse, I'm sure we can have more precise answer

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing it first while specifying the encoding, then reading the table, as here: [readHTMLTable and UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965520/readhtmltable-and-utf-8-encoding).

An example might be:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles"
doc <- htmlParse(url, encoding = "UTF-8") #this will preserve characters
tables <- as.data.frame(readHTMLTable(doc, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
Sec <- tables[[6]]
#not sure what you're trying to do here though
pl1R1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(Sec[,2]), ' '))[seq(2,32, 4)]
```